# Wrong output when writing a SQL query using Postgis functions

Tags: php, postgresql, subquery, postgis, psql

I am doing my homework, and I am about done with it. The problem is the last query that I right is only supposed to return 10 rows, but what I have right now returns 16 rows, and I can't figure out what I did wrong. The definition of the query is

```
Find all urban areas that (1) have a combined land & water area of greater than 1500 square 
kilo- meters and (2) intersect multiple states. Your query should return the urban area name 
(name10) and a count of the number of states intersected. The results should be first ordered by 
the number of states intersected (in descending order) and secondarily by alphabetical order of 
the urban area names from (A to Z). (Note: Pay very close attention to the units used for the 
areas in this question.) (10 records)
```

The SQL query that I wrote that returns 16 records is

```
SELECT area1.name10, COUNT(*) AS Count 
FROM tl_2010_us_uac10 AS area1, tl_2010_us_state10 AS area2 
WHERE ((area1.aland10 + area1.awater10)/1000) > 1500 
AND ST_Intersects(area1.coords, area2.coords) 
GROUP BY area1.name10 HAVING COUNT(*) > 2 
ORDER BY Count DESC, area1.name10 ASC;
```

The two tables that I am using are

```
Table "public.tl_2010_us_state10"
    Column   |            Type             |                            Modifiers                             
 ------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------
  gid        | integer                     | not null default 
  region10   | character varying(2)        | 
  division10 | character varying(2)        | 
  statefp10  | character varying(2)        | 
  statens10  | character varying(8)        | 
  geoid10    | character varying(2)        | 
  stusps10   | character varying(2)        | 
  name10     | character varying(100)      |
  lsad10     | character varying(2)        | 
  mtfcc10    | character varying(5)        | 
  funcstat10 | character varying(1)        | 
  aland10    | double precision            | 
  awater10   | double precision            | 
  intptlat10 | character varying(11)       | 
  intptlon10 | character varying(12)       | 
  coords     | geometry(MultiPolygon,4326) | 

 Indexes:
 "tl_2010_us_state10_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (gid)
 "tl_2010_us_state10_coords_gist" gist (coords)
```

Then this is the table of the urban information.

```
                                      Table "public.tl_2010_us_uac10"
    Column   |            Type             |                           Modifiers                         
 ------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------
 gid        | integer                     | not null default 
 uace10     | character varying(5)        | 
 geoid10    | character varying(5)        | 
 name10     | character varying(100)      |
 namelsad10 | character varying(100)      | 
 lsad10     | character varying(2)        | 
 mtfcc10    | character varying(5)        | 
 uatyp10    | character varying(1)        | 
 funcstat10 | character varying(1)        | 
 aland10    | double precision            | 
 awater10   | double precision            | 
 intptlat10 | character varying(11)       | 
 intptlon10 | character varying(12)       | 
 coords     | geometry(MultiPolygon,4326) | 

 Indexes:
"tl_2010_us_uac10_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (gid)
"tl_2010_us_uac10_coords_gist" gist (coords)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Area is given in square meters.  To convert square meters to square kilometers, divide by 1,000,000 - not 1,000.

1 km = 1,000m.  1km**2 = (1,000m)**2 = 1,000,000(m**2)

Comment: Yes, it does say pay very close attention to the units in the question :D.